# Issues -Restoring HBase image

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using HDP 2.6
I am facing some issues while restoring a backup image in HBase.
The steps I have followed is here :
https://hortonworks.com/blog/coming-hdp-2-5-incremental-backup-restore-apache-hbase-apache-phoenix/
We tried the following :

- 1) take a full backup

hbase backup create full hdfs:///tmp/full test

- 2) restore the data

  hbase restore hdfs:///tmp/bakup-hbase backup_id test1 -overwrite

Exception:
java.io.IOException: Could not find backup manifest .backup.manifest for backup_id in hdfs:///tmp/bakup-hbase. Did backup_ correspond to previously taken backup ?

I am trying to restore the image of test into a table test1.Both test and test1 has same column fmily structure
I figured out that the backup manifest file is created inside hdfs:///tmp/bakup-hbase/backup_//default folder.

So, I copied the manifest file inside hdfs:///tmp/bakup-hbase/backup_ folder .Still the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the above issue.
I will post the answer , so that it might help someone else.
1) The issue was occurring because I was trying to restore the image into a different table (with the same column family structure).
If there is a need to restore the image into a separate table then this the command that should be used

```
hbase restore hdfs:///tmp/bakup-hbase backup_id test test1
```

2) To append a incremental backup image into a existing table this is the step that should be followed.

```
hbase restore hdfs:///tmp/bakup-hbase backup_id test -check -overwrite
```

The check option asks to restore all the dependant images to the image id specified in the restore command.
This needs to be done as there are no other way to append data from a backup image to a existing table